# How to start xorg in Arch Linux virtual machine running top of FreeBSD's bhyve?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, freebsd, virtual-machine, bhyve

I'm trying to start KDE Plasma and SDDM with virtualized Arch Linux. The host is FreeBSD running bhyve. Bootloader is UEFI.

Looking at the virtual display with VNC connection with remmina (VNC viewer) ends with systemd log saying:

```
Reached target Graphical Interface.
```

but xorg doesn't launch and switch to graphical mode. Am I missing a driver or configuration or some bhyve-specific guest tools or kernel boot parameter?

I've also installed tigervnc and when connecting to it with remmina KDE works just fine, so the virtual "physical" display seems to be the problem.

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[   124.544] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   124.544] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   124.544] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

`lspci -vvvvvvvv`:

```
...

00:1d.0 VGA compatible controller: Device fb5d:40fb (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Region 0: Memory at c1007400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128]
        Region 1: Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000

...
```

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "fb0"
        Driver     "fbdev"
        # PCI 00:1d.0, 0x1d = 29
        BusID      "PCI:0:29:0"
EndSection
```

```
$ pacman -Qsq xf86-video
xf86-video-fbdev
xf86-video-qxl
xf86-video-vesa
```

Comment: Doesn't work with an empty xorg.conf, either?

Comment: @MarcusMüller same `Reached target Graphical Interface.` result with empty config.